# Display One Hide And Show Section At a Time Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show and hide certain sections of a web page without showing or hiding other elements with similar names for example I want to be able to show a certain comments replies without displaing another comments replies that have the same class names. But I cant seem to get my jquery to work right. In-other words I want to click the a element with a class `view-comments` and display the closest section with a class name with `more-comments`

Here is my simplified HTML code.

HTML

```
        <article>
            <div>
                <div>
                    ....
                    <a class="view-comments" title="" href="">View Comments</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="more-comments">
                .......
            </section>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div>
                <div>
                    ....
                    <a class="view-comments" title="" href="">View Comments</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="more-comments">
                .......
            </section>
        </article>


        <article>
            <div>
                <div>
                    ....
                    <a class="view-comments" title="" href="">View Comments</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="more-comments">
                .......
            </section>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div>
                <div>
                    ....
                    <a class="view-comments" title="" href="">View Comments</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="more-comments">
                .......
            </section>
        </article>
```

Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.view-comments').click(function() {
        $('.more-comments').toggle($(this).hasClass('view-comments'));
        $(this).toggleClass('view-comments hide-comments');
      });
    });
```

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/a8zbuj80/1 is this what you want

Answer (score 1):

To do this, I would make all of the elements that dont have the class `active` hidden by default. Then, when you click on a link (call prevent default to stop page navigation), remove the class`active` from all of the `more-comments` sections, then add the class `active` to the closest `more-comments` section

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.view-comments').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.more-comments').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('article').find('.more-comments').addClass('active');
      });
    });
```

```css
.more-comments:not(.active){
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
            <div>
                <div>
                    ....
                    <a class="view-comments " title="" href="">View Comments</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="more-comments active">
                .......more-comments 1
            </section>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div>
                <div>
                    ....
                    <a class="view-comments" title="" href="">View Comments</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="more-comments">
                ....... more-comments 2
            </section>
        </article>


        <article>
            <div>
                <div>
                    ....
                    <a class="view-comments" title="" href="">View Comments</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="more-comments">
                ....... more-comments 3
            </section>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div>
                <div>
                    ....
                    <a class="view-comments" title="" href="">View Comments</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <section class="more-comments">
                ....... more-comments 4
            </section>
        </article>
```

Comment: May I ask what e.preventDefault(); is and what does it actually do if I remove it? Thanks.

Comment: Your `view-comments` elements are links, by default links navigate to the address stored in their `href` property. When you c lick such a link, it will navigate to the page in it's href before the bound jQuery function is called (or at least before the results are seen). `e.preventDefault();` prevents that from happening

Comment: Note that this assumes that you only want one section to be visible at a time (generally desired) but if you'd like to be able to open multiple sections at the same time, use @Pekka's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.view-comments').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).closest('article').find('.more-comments').toggle();
 });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8zbuj80/2/)

Try this way

Comment: Personally, I prefer `$(this).closest('article').find('.more-comments').toggle();` as it is less likely to break with changes to the `html` structure. but +1 :)

Comment: pls @DelightedD0D include to answer as update. or if you want i can do it for you.thank you for the suggestion